# Ubuntu deleted windows 7

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7, data-recovery

I have downloaded ubuntu 14.04 and trying to install it on my laptop, but after installation completed, I seen that ubuntu deleted my windows 7. i never permitted to do so. then why it happens. I want my windows 7 as its back. reply with any possible options. ASAP.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Comment: Are you sure that Windows partition is gone? 
In Ubuntu: 
Press the `start` key on keyboard. 
Type `Disks`. Open the Disks application. 
Do you see your windows partition here?

Comment: no dear, there are no partitions

Comment: it seems while installing ubuntu it formated my windows 7 too. i dont care about windows but the thing is i want my data back in any condition. can u please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu, if you select Erase HDD or Remove Windows 7 or you install Ubuntu in windows 7 system partition, don't have any way to restore Windows 7.

If not. Try repair boot follow the instructions in: [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: thanks for reply, while installing ubuntu, it shows me that it will replace "D" drive from windows, but after installation it wipe out my all data. the main problem is, is there any option to recover my personal data. waiting for reply.